# How do I dynamically create a mySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create mysql query dynamically as shown below but got stucked in the below part.
Not sure what is wrong here.can anyone help

```
<?php    
$rating=$_GET['rating'];
$where = '';
if(isset($_GET['rating'])){
$data = implode(',',$rating); 
$where = "AND WHERE rating IN($data)";
}
$query = "select * from shops WHERE city='Mumbai' $where";
```

Comment: What's your *actual* issue?

Comment: This translates to using 2x `WHERE` clauses; remove one. `$where = "AND rating IN($data)";`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and if using `mysqli_` add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap each value in single quotes to pass them into `IN` in `WHERE` clause :

```
$data = is_array($rating) ? "'" . implode("', '",$rating) . "'" : "'$rating'";
```

Also remove second `WHERE` :

```
$where = "AND rating IN($data)";
```

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/a4363282/public_html/pune/pune.php on line 44

Comment: @user3541562 : It happens because `$rating` isn't of array type. Updated.Also don't forget that `IN` requires at least one parameter, so if $rating is empty, then will be thrown error .

Answer (score 0):

You are using WHERE two times. Take it out from below

```
$where = "AND WHERE rating IN($data)";
```

It should be only

```
$where = "AND rating IN($data)";
```